# Multiple histograms in one plot

Tags: r

I have at least 5 tables as shown below (table1 and table2). I want to plot the histogram for A, T, G, C columns for each position (Pos) column. I want to plot both tables in one plot. How can I do this in R?

```
table1<- structure(list(Pos = 1:19, A = c(48L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 26L, 34L, 
    18L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 243L), C = c(13L, 
    2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 
    9L, 1L, 84L), G = c(12L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 
    7L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 45L), T = c(32L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 
    4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 14L, 226L
    )), .Names = c("Pos", "A", "C", "G", "T"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -19L))

table2<- structure(list(Pos = 1:19, A = c(48L, 12L, 9L, 8L, 26L, 34L, 
18L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 12L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 243L), C = c(13L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 
9L, 1L, 84L), G = c(12L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 
7L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 45L), T = c(32L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 12L, 16L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 14L, 226L
)), .Names = c("Pos", "A", "C", "G", "T"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *"histogram"* and *"for each position (Pos) column"*. That means that `table1` alone has 19 histograms, `table2 has another 19, etc. How do you expect a histogram to look with 5*19=95 different hists? ("Perhaps" I'm misunderstanding :-)

Comment: ? `par(mfrow = c(2,1)); barplot(t(table1)[-1, ], beside = TRUE); barplot(t(table2)[-1, ], beside = TRUE)`

Comment: @r2evans I want to plot A, T, G, C levels with `Pos` column in X axis, but I want to plot both table 1 and table 2 in a single figure.

Comment: @rawr Yes you are right. This is what I want, but how do you do this in ggplot? with proper legends?

Comment: Might be more interesting if tables 1 and 2 were not identical :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, combine the tables and add a column to identify the table using `dplyr::bind_rows`. Then you can facet on `table`.

For side-by-side plots, use `+ facet_grid(~table)` instead.

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(table1, table2, .id = "table") %>%  
  gather(base, value, -Pos, -table) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Pos, value)) + 
    geom_col(aes(fill = base), position = position_dodge()) +
    facet_grid(table~.)
```

[image]